# Reducer name in StoreModule.forRoot()

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

My question is why does the name of the two highlighted `count` below need to be the same for the application to work? The doc says forRoot take a reducer as an argument, but why the name of the reducer in forRoot should be the same as the state (count in this case)? I don't see this mentioned anywhere in the doc, thanks!

imports: [BrowserModule, StoreModule.forRoot({ `count`: counterReducer })],

constructor(private store: Store<{ `count`: number }>) {
this.count$ = store.select('count');
}

(The example is from https://ngrx.io/guide/store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forRoot` (and `forFeature`) build up the state tree, in this example you end up with the following state tree:

```
{
  count: 0
}
```

`select` reads from the state tree, and you have to start at the top level, that's why it needs to be `count`, because it reads the `count` property from the state tree.

An example with a bigger state:

```
{
  customers: {
    persons: {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Would result in the following select to get the persons

```
store.select('customers', 'persons')
```